# Is there a name for all numbers different than zero?

Tags: terminology, numbers

> The names for the number 0 include "zero", "cipher", "null", "naught", "nought", "love", "duck", "nil", "nada", "zilch", "zip", "o", "aught", and "ought". There are various subtleties of usage amongst them all.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_for_the_number_0_in_English)

Ok right. 0 has a lot of name. I am looking for a word to name a number or a group of number who can be any digits but strictly not equals to 0. Positive, negative, complex, whatever but 0. When I search about opposite of 0, I found about -0 but it is still 0.

Is there a name for all numbers different than zero?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be about programming terminology rather than English.

Comment: @David I was looking for an english term without success. I used my programming background to find the answer, but the answer itself is a basic english term. If I am off-topic, I would like to know how (a meta link would be nice :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In programming, we would write this as `not 0` or `!0`. If we search about not 0 number or non 0 number we find an answer.

## nonzero number

> A quantity which does not equal zero is said to be nonzero. A real nonzero number must be either positive or negative, and a complex nonzero number can have either real or imaginary part nonzero.

[wolfram.com](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Nonzero.html)

> **A nonzero number** is any number that is not equal to zero. This includes both positive and negative numbers as well as fractions and irrational numbers.

[reference.com](https://www.reference.com/math/nonzero-number-6bc8b94af07b8b5a)

> Chemists, mathematicians and scientists who complete equations in their research consider all nonzero numbers to have meaning or significance whether the number is negative or positive. Any number, whether positive or negative, that does not equate to zero essentially represents a nonzero number.

[sciencing.com](https://sciencing.com/nonzero-number-6672865.html)

Also on math.stackexchange.com:

> An integer is any whole number or its negative, e.g. ..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ...
>
> A non-zero integer is any of these but 0.

[What does non-zero integer mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063048/what-does-non-zero-integer-mean)

Comment: Well, if it is about programming, then not-null also connotes a value which is not a null. It is opposite of null (one among many def. of zero as you pointed out), yes null is not a zero, it simple means absences of value. –

Comment: @Ubihatt Yes, the difference between a board with 0 written on it and one with nothing written on it.